# Remove Firefox camera and microphone icons from menu bar

Tags: menu-bar, firefox

Firefox (121.0) insists on showing icons in the menu bar when a website accesses microphone and camera:

[image]

Since macOS Sonoma there's a built-in feature that does exactly that, so I'd like to remove the Firefox icons, how do I do that?

- There doesn't seem to be anything in the Firefox settings for that.
- Neither
  `privacy.webrtc.hideGlobalIndicator`/`privacy.webrtc.legacyGlobalIndicator`
  nor using `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` has
  any effect on the menu bar icons.
- <kbd>⌘ + Drag</kbd> doesn't work for these icons.
- I'm aware of 3rd-party tools like Bartender but I don't want to use them (their approach is a bit janky).

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: try Firefox update 121.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: @Ruskes I have, no luck unfortunately.